# Wordpress + WP Ecommerce plugin - custom description field

Tags: e-commerce, wordpress

I need to create additional description field for each product category.
I am using [this code](http://pastebin.com/F2K22XDs) to create additional field for regular WP category.

I guess that I have to modify something in order to get this additional field to show up, but I’m really not aware what

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Advanced Custom Fields plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) for this. This plugin is very nicely written and gives you to create group of fields to any post type.